# Versão 5.3 Laravel com php 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Boa tarde.

Eu utilizo a versão 5.0 do Laravel e um dos requisitos dessa versão é que o php tem que ser maior ou igual a 5.4. Até aí tudo certo, meu php instalado é o 5.6.32.

Porém eu queria começar a utilizar a versão 5.3 do Laravel e essa versão necessita  de um php maior ou igual a 5.6.4. Tentei atualizar a versão do php no meu xampp, mas no site oficial deles não tem a versão 5.6.4. http://php.net/downloads.php

A minha dúvida é, se consigo utilizar o Laravel 5.3 com a versão 5.4.32 do meu php?

Ou se alguém puder me passar um tutorial de como atualizar a versão do php para essa 5.6.4 eu agradeço.

Att,
Maurício.

Comment: Não, se o requisito básico é `PHP >= 5.6.4` o Laravel só pode ser utilizado assim. O que se pode fazer? Você pode baixar a versão do PHP correspondente e utilizar ele via console! com o seu servidor embutido ...

Comment: Ta bem então! Obrigado.

Comment: Ou substitua a versão do PHP do Xampp